# SQL Count + Running Total in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, cumulative-sum

I'm fairly new to SQL so please bear with me.
I have a table (DataTable) with a date column (Date) and count column(Count)

- 01/01/2015 10
- 01/02/2015 9
- 01/03/2015 12
- 01/04/2015 7
- 01/05/2015 8
- 01/06/2015 10
- 01/07/2015 10
- 01/08/2015 8
- 01/09/2015 9
- 01/10/2015 10
- 01/11/2015 11
- 01/12/2015 11

I need to create a new table that has calculated the: count, running total, running financial year, running 12 months. Then added these all into one column and add a new category column that separates these sums by 'month', 'Contract to Date', 'Financial Year' and '12 months to end month'.

1. The Month shows the count for that month
2. The Contract to Date is just like a running total from start date to end date
3. The Financial year starts at June and acts like a running total until it reaches May of the next year after which the coming June has its count reset
4. The 12 months to end month adds the previous 11 months to the current month

The result would be

- 01/01/2015 10 Month
- 01/02/2015 9  Month
- 01/03/2015 12 Month
- 01/04/2015 7  Month
- 01/05/2015 8  Month
- 01/06/2015 10 Month
- 01/07/2015 10 Month
- 01/08/2015 8  Month
- 01/09/2015 9  Month
- 01/10/2015 10 Month
- 01/11/2015 11 Month
- 01/12/2015 11 Month
- 01/01/2015 10 Contract to Date
- 01/02/2015 19 Contract to Date
- 01/03/2015 31 Contract to Date
- 01/04/2015 39 Contract to Date
- 01/05/2015 47 Contract to Date
- 01/06/2015 57 Contract to Date
- 01/07/2015 67 Contract to Date
- 01/08/2015 75 Contract to Date
- 01/09/2015 84 Contract to Date
- 01/10/2015 94 Contract to Date
- 01/11/2015 105 Contract to Date
- 01/12/2015 116 Contract to Date
- etc

How would would I program this all in a single query (without having to create 4 separate tables)
I need to use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 or 2008r2
As far as I could research:

```
SELECT * INTO DataTableFinal FROM (
SELECT Date, Count
FROM DataTable
UNION All
SELECT Date, Count = Sum (Count) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM DataTable
UNION All
SELECT Date, Count =
FROM DataTable
UNION All
SELECT Date, Count =
FROM DataTable
) as tmp
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think sql server 2008 supports `sum()` with `order by` in window function. Try something like this

```
SELECT dates,[Count],'MOnth'
FROM   Yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT dates,run,'Contract to Date'
FROM   Yourtable a
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([Count])
                    FROM   Yourtable  b
                    WHERE  a.dates >= b.dates) cs (run)
```

[***SQLFIDDLE DEMO***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea875/2)

Comment: Thanks that worked, I've managed to get the 12 months to end date to work but I can't seem to figure out the Financial year (which starts in June for Australia)

Answer (score 0):

End result:

```
SELECT dates,[Count],'Month'                    
FROM   Yourtable                    
UNION ALL                   
SELECT dates,cnt,'Contract to Date'                 
FROM   Yourtable a                  
    CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([Count])            
        FROM   Yourtable b
        WHERE  a.dates >= b.dates) cs (cnt)
UNION ALL                   
SELECT dates,cnt,'12 Months to End Date'                    
FROM   Yourtable a                  
    CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([Count])            
    FROM   Yourtable b
    WHERE  a.dates >= b.dates and b.dates >= DATEADD(month, -12, a.dates)) cs (cnt) 
UNION ALL                   
SELECT dates,cnt,'Financial Year'                   
FROM   Yourtable a                  
    CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([Count])            
        FROM   Yourtable b
        WHERE  a.dates >= b.dates and b.dates >= DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(month,'19100701',a.dates)/12,'19100701')) cs (cnt)
```